# cropping tools for admin panel cms

Tags: php, javascript, image, crop

Is there any tools (JS & PHP) that can crop image and upload and save it based on what of width and height that we specify?

Most of them only tools for resize and not cropping of what inserted width and height that we specify.

Is there any good tool for this (JS & PHP) that I can use for my web admin panel / CMS.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a drop-in solution, or are you asking us how to resize&crop images?

Comment: see http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

Comment: I am looking for a tool (js/php) that ready to be use for admin page/cms. Easy to use and integrate. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I used that before. Is there any other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am looking for.. Works perfectly!!!

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/working-with-the-jcrop-plugin/